# What happened to Builder::XmlMarkup in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, atom-feed

I'm struggling with the `atom_feed` method in a RoR 3 project. The method complains about an

```
undefined local variable or method `xml'
```

error so I tried passing the XML builder as an option to the atom_feed (i e `atom_feed({:xml => Builder::XmlMarkup.new})`) but when doing so I get a `NameError: uninitialized constant Builder` exception instead.

Does anyone know why I'm getting either the first or the second exception?

Answer (score 12):

```
 require 'active_support/builder' unless defined?(Builder)
```